# json formatting error with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

This is the JSON response I'm getting. Javascript alert says JSON error and couldn't to be parsed! I'm confused as to what causes this problem.

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":"4","iTotalDisplayRecords":"4","aaData":[["59","474","1838937873"],  
["60","520","1838937873"],["61","520","100004515813901"],["62","474","0"]]}              

Array
(
   [sEcho] => 1
   [iTotalRecords] => 4
   [iTotalDisplayRecords] => 4
  [aaData] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 59
                [1] => 474
                [2] => 1838937873
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 60
                [1] => 520
                [2] => 1838937873
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 61
                [1] => 520
                [2] => 100004515813901
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 62
                [1] => 474
                [2] => 0
            )

    )

)
```

This is the Script I'm using in HTML page

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "id" },
                    { "mData": "cab_id" },
                    { "mData": "user_id" }


                ]
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

Comment: have you tries http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json

Comment: The above json is a valid json. Check your dataTable plugin version.

Comment: json seems to be ok. how you are parsing?

Comment: Will I get the result in my table with the given Script?

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam : version     1.9.4

Comment: I think the problem is with mData: "id" where mData is a function in dataTable

Comment: Yes hopefully! But How can I format the script so that I can get the desired result on to HTML table?

Comment: @AhsanShah : Is that the script you were asking ?

Comment: Just remove "aoColumns": [{ "mData": "id" },{ "mData": "cab_id" },{ "mData": "user_id" }] and check out the results

Comment: Error still persists !

Comment: Are you decoding as an array??

Comment: No , as JSON itself ! echo json_encode( $output );